# Get Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null' error when fetching some movie info from the MovieDB api

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I tried a tutorial to create a movie application. It works fine to get popular movies but with the same code to get upcoming movies I got this error and UI doesn't show anything. The error is :
Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type 'Null'

here is where error happens:

```
  Future<List<Movie>> getPopularMovies({required int page}) async {
    //we are going to get Response
    Response _response =
        await _http.request('/movie/popular', query: {'page': page});
    if (_response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String?, dynamic> _data = _response.data;
      List<Movie> _movies = _data['results'].map<Movie>((_movieData) {
        return Movie.fromJson(_movieData);
      }).toList();
      return _movies;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Couldn\'t get the popular movies');
    }
  }

  Future<List<Movie>> getUpcomingMovies({required int page}) async {
    //we are going to get Response
    Response _response =
        await _http.request('/movie/upcoming', query: {'page': page});
    if (_response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String?, dynamic> _data = _response.data;
      List<Movie> _movies = _data['results'].map<Movie>((_movieData) {
        return Movie.fromJson(_movieData);
      }).toList();
      return _movies;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Couldn\'t get the popular movies');
    }
  }
```

I tried `jsonDecode(_response.data)` but got the this error: Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type '_JsonMap'

[image]

Comment: use null safety  "!"

Comment: Where to use "!"?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some particular field in your model class may receive null value from response...that's why flutter indicates error....

To avoid this you have to make the field nullable using (?)...

Example:

int? rank;

Inside constructor remove required keyword for that field.

Now it will accepts null values...

Comment: Thanks, tried ? in model but got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Can solve your problem

```
Future<List<Movie>> getUpcomingMovies({required int page}) async {
    List<Movie> list = [];
    Response _response = http
        .request('/movie/upcoming', query: {'page': page})
        .then((_response) {
      setState(() {
        var list = json.decode(_response.body);
        //categories = list.map((category) => Category.fromJson(category)).toList();
        if (list is List) {
          Map<String?, dynamic> _data = _response.data;
          List<Movie> _movies = _data['results'].map<Movie>((_movieData) {
            return Movie.fromJson(_movieData);
          }).toList();
          return _movies;
        }
       else {
      print('response is not list');
      }
      });
  }

  );
    
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I didn't access to setState , Whats the problem with my code?

Comment: remove setState and try again